# "Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_open_v2' in DLL 'sqlite3'.":""

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I am working on a windows forms application. when I run the application on windows 8 (VS2012), the application runs upto an extent and then crashes, giving the exception "{"Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}".

I downloaded the 32 bit SQLite3 and added it to my solution. thereafter I got the error

> {"Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_open_v2' in DLL
>   'sqlite3'.":""}.

I am running my application in the release mode.
kindly help me fix this issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Is your application running as x86 or x64? You may want to check your build configuration.

Comment: my application is running as x86 in the release mode.